# Big O Notation - Fibonnaci - Cracking the Coding interview example 14, page 53

Tags: big-o

I'm reading the "Cracking the Coding Interview" book, chapter VI Big(O). On page 53, the author shows this code and asks: what is the time complexity of it?

```
    void allFib(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
        }
    }

    int fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
```

He says it's not O(n * 2^n) but O(2^n) because:

- fib(1) --> 2^1 steps
- fib(2) --> 2^2 steps
- fib(3) --> 2^3 steps
- ...
- fib(n) --> 2^n steps

and so, the total amount of work is 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^n = 2^(n+1) = O(2^n).

My question is: why is fib(2) = 4 steps? The way I see it, it's 5: fib(2) = 2 steps (first two if statements) + fib(1) + fib(0) = 2 + 2 + 1 = 5.

Comment: What do you define as `step`?

Comment: The author doesn't specify, but I'm guessing it's statements/instructions and that's why he says fib(1) = 2 (it has to go through the 2 ifs)

Answer (score 0):

As n=2 so below line of code will be executed

```
return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
```

above line of code execution will take 2 steps. one step for fib(2-1) and one step for fib(2-2). So total=2 steps performed.

There are no more recursion operations left to do as both terms in the line of code have been resolved to actual values:

Now values are 1 and 0 and against value 1, below line will be executed

```
else if (n == 1)
```

One step added to execute above line of code. Now Total steps=3

again now only 0 value remaining and against value 0 below line of code will be executed

```
if (n <= 0)
```

above line of code will take one step to execute. Now total steps=3+1=4

So to execute Fib(2),  time complexity will be O(2^2)=4 steps

I hope it helped you to understand the execution of steps.

Refer to the [Recursive Fibonacci Method Explained](https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e) for more details.

Comment: "Now values are 1 and 0 and against value 1, below line will be executed
else if (n == 1)". For me this is not correct since the first condition is also evaluated (if n<=0)

Comment: For me, A statement will be executed if condition is true otherwise  this statement is ignored, and nothing is executed. So when n==1, First it will evaluate the first condition i.e n<=0 but as 1>0 so this statement will be terminated when next n==1 statement will be evaluated and because statement is true, It will performed a step i.e return 1

Comment: We both agree that the statement inside "if(n<=0)" is not executed. But I do think that we have to take into account the evaluation of the if statement. If we don't, then how is fib(1) = 2  (according to the author and included in my original post)? It should be 1 if we follow your logic.

Comment: Time complexity of Fibonacci series is 2^n+1. if n=2 then as per your observation it should take 5 steps not 4 steps but as per the author it's equal to 2^n not 2^n+1. Basically, when we talk about Big-O Notation, then always computational time complexity calculated not exact one and constant complexity always skipped only variable complexity considered because constant has no value in Big-O notation. if you read about Upper bound(Big-O) and lower bound, then idea will be cleared in your mind and it will help you to understand  Time complexity variation in case of Upper Bound and lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

You will get lost if you focus too much on the details. You already know that fib(n) takes O(2^n) time. If we call allFib() with the value of 5, for example, the for loop will call fib() with values 0 through 4, meaning to get the total runtime, we have to add the runtimes for fib(0)+fib(1)+...+fib(4).

Knowing that the runtime for fib(n) takes O(2^n) time, replace n with the current for-loop index to get the runtime.

- fib(0) - 2^0
- fib(1) - 2^1
- fib(2) - 2^2
- fib(3) - 2^3
- fib(4) - 2^4

Then add (2^0)+(2^1)+(2^2)+(2^3)+(2^4)+...(2^n) = 2^(n+1) = O(2^n)